# java: Runtime.exec() Thread and errorOutput, readLine

Tags: java, readline, runtime.exec

I got very common thread hang condition although I don't understand why it happens.
I have 2 threads: main() and errorStreamReaderThread

**In the main thread:**
- execute external process via Runtime.exec()
- create new errorStreamReaderThread to consume error output stream
- perform manipulations on input and output streams of external process( execute commands and read output of the commands)
- send exit command to external process
- set interrupt flag for errorStreamReaderThread
- waitFor() for external process to terminate
- return rc of the external process

**In the errorStreamReaderThread:**
- perform Buffered readLine on error stream while !interruptedFlag &&(line=br.readLine())!=null (errorStream is passed from external process from main)
- perform log error stream

---

I expect that even though readLine() block on stream - as soon as originator of this stream is finished (external process in this case) this readLine should be interrupted.

Observed behavior 
- everything works fine 95% of the time - no hangs, both threads: main and error threads are finished and program finished.
- about 5% it hangs
- main thread is finished (waitFor is returned)
- errorStreamReaderThread is blocked on BufferedReader.readLine (in fact the error stream for this buffered reader is no longer exists, since external process is finished)

Additional environment factor is that this java class is executed as oracle java function (it is wrapped in the oracle)

Please let me know what I'm missing here and why I got this readLine hangs on the non existing errorStream

thank you

Answer (score 0):

> in fact the error stream for this buffered reader is no longer exists,
>   since external process is finished

Do you guess that this is the case because you have sent an exit command to the external process, or have you really checked both cases?

Since BufferedReader.readLine() will no longer block but return null once the socket closes, I don't think the socket has closed...

Comment: waitFor() for external process returned and I assume according to spec  that external process terminated.

spec says: "waitFor() causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated. This method returns immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess exits."

Comment: So I agree with you that if external is terminated - errorStream should be closed - no hang in readLine. 

If I see hang in readLine smth wrong going here. I suspect that it caused by oracle wrapper ( this java code is stored oracle java function) or some bug involved

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "it is wrapped in the oracle" and "this java code is stored oracle java function"?

Comment: this class is published as oracle function and executed from oracle function call e.g. : <br>

loadjava -user scott/tiger -oci8 aaa/plsquick/ demos/Hello.java AND

CREATE FUNCTION hello_there (to_whom IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'aaa.plsquick.demos.Hello.publishedMethod (java.lang.String) return java.lang.String'; / 

So I'm trying to understand if this post mortem existence of errorThread and lock on it is caused by oracle execution environment.